# Bertrand’s Postulate apply for computer science

Tags: nt.number-theory

Find the least integer $k_n$ s.t. $1^2,2^2,...,n^2$ are all incongruent modulo $k_n$ for $n\geq4$.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: This doesn't really look like homework. But generally it would be better to avoid the imperative mode when posting questions.

Comment: Thanks Noah Schweber. I'm not good at English.

Comment: @quangdo Your guess that Bertrand's postulate applies was completely right!

Answer (score 5):

The answer appeared in the following paper:

L. K. Arnold, S. J. Benkoski and B. J. McCabe, *The discriminator (a simple application of Bertrand’s postulate)*, Amer. Math. Monthly 92 (1985), 275–277.

For each $n=5,6,\ldots$, the number $k_n$ is the smallest integer $m \ge 2n$ such that $m$ is $p$ or $2p$ with $p$ an odd prime.

For some further developments, you may look at my talk [*On primes in arithmetic progressions*](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/Prime-AP.pdf).

Comment: Thanks you very much, Zhi-Wei Sun.